# JQuery replacing form elements with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am in a situation, where I need to convert my form filled data to a text before submitting.

Like for example, the form may have a name field and an email field. I will fill the form with details, then when I click export as text, I need to get the contents of the html in text format

```html
name = <input type="text" name="name" /> <!-- user enters "john" -->
email = <input type="text" name="email" /> <!-- user enters a@b.com -->
```

when I export I need

```
name = john
email = a@b.com
```

Currently, I am using this code to convert. But the problem is, once I convert I am not able to get back to previous state.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   $('.replace').replaceWith(function(){
       return this.value
    });
});
```

So, what I thought was, I will display the output in a div tag. But if I try

```
document.getelementByID("parentdiv").value
```

I am unable to get the form values.

Any suggestions please?

**Update:**

serialize is not working as expected. The above one is a small example. The form is so complex and I need to visually render the form values to its labels.

Comment: The values already are strings/text?

Comment: Would you consider [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

Comment: am not using the form for submitting, i am using it to generate some content.

Comment: Would you consider [`.serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)?

Comment: Go with `.serialize()` as pointed above.

Comment: Can you then show the complex form? Otherwise this might become a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If I understood correctly you also want to change the text back to html?

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = $('form').serialize();
```

This will give you a string of elements and values which you can easily work with, it's intended to use as JSON, however for your intended purpose it should be fairly easy to fiddle around with.

It will give you an output similar to

name=John&x=y

Comment: Was about to mention is not an array, but if you do want an array use [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)

Comment: Aye, my bad, amended :)

Answer (score 1):

try like this using `serializeArray()`:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  var x = $('form').serializeArray();
  console.log(x);
  var str="";
  $.each(x, function( index, val ) {
    str=str+val.name+":"+val.value+"<br>";
   });
     $('#textFrom').html(str);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 name =<input type="text" name="name" /> <!--user enters "john"-->
email =<input type="text" name="email" /> <!--//user enters a@b.com-->
</form>
<button id="btn">click</button>
<div id="textFrom"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is useful. But the form has more than 150 + elements, i will have to again render it using another set of codes. But the earlier method gives me flexibility to just see if the form is filled correctly. :(

Comment: then try to use JSON.stringify or JSON.parse.it can help.but the above answer won't be that slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery serialize function :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("div").text($("form").serialize());
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="Tina" /><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="tina@yopmail.com" /><br>
</form>
<button>Export Values</button>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output will be : name=Tina&LastName=tina%40yopmail.com